# How to format java.util.Date with <fmt:formatDate>

Tags: jsp, date, jstl

I have a simple Java web app in which I am trying to format a `Date` object by using JSP EL and JSTL. The following code returns nothing:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${game.releaseDate}" type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure this is related to _JavaScript_?

Comment: To avoid the obvious, is the `fmt` taglib properly declared? What do you see in JSP-generated HTML output via rightclick, *View page source* in webbrowser? Do you still see `<fmt:formatDate>` tag unparsed over there?

Comment: game.releaseDate is null?

Comment: @BalusC I had the `ftm` taglib declared in a separate `head.jsp` file. I changed it so that it had the declaration in `games.jsp` and now it works but I'd still like to know why it didn't work with the external declaration.

Comment: Because it applied to `head.jsp` only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have imported all the required taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<c:if test="${not empty game.releaseDate}">
    <fmt:formatDate value="${game.releaseDate}"type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
</c:if>
```

or better

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty game.releaseDate}">
        No available date
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <fmt:formatDate value="${game.releaseDate}"type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" />
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```